# PCL and ros::Time

Tags: pcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I was looking through this example and..
http://wiki.ros.org/pcl_ros

PointCloud::Ptr msg (new PointCloud);
msg->header.stamp = ros::Time::now ();

The second line where the stamp takes the time from the ros::time function does not work. Is there any reason to it or a workaround to directly use the current time?

Basically the compilation error is as follows:
error: cannot convert ‘ros::Time’ to ‘uint64_t {aka long long unsigned int}’ in assignment

Running hydro btw. Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/172241/pcl-and-ros::time/) by [Yuan Huang](https://answers.ros.org/users/13541/yuan-huang/) on ROS Answers with karma: 48 on 2014-05-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ros::Time time_st = ros::Time::now ();

msg->header.stamp = time_st.toNSec()/1e3;

From what I saw in the pcl_conversion header. for hydro there is no toPCL for time but for indigo there is.

Probably the wiki should be updated since hydro is using the newer PCL.

---

Originally posted by [Yuan Huang](https://answers.ros.org/users/13541/yuan-huang/) with karma: 48 on 2014-05-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3